# How to prevent using a named_scope from creating n+1 queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, arel

What is the best way to prevent ActiveRecord from making an unnecessary query when referencing a list of models that already been loaded?

```
class Checklist
  has_many :checklist_items
  scope :active, where(active: true)
end
class ChecklistItem
  belongs_to :checklist
  scope :active, where(active: true)
end


@checklists = Checklist.active.includes(:checklist_items).where(checklist_items: {active: true})

# Works fine, does NOT make extra SQL query
@checklists[0].checklist_items

# Makes extra query. How do I prevent this?
@checklists[0].checklist_items.active
```

### What is the best work around for preventing this extra query when using a named_scope?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you use `where`, you'll trigger another query.  If you think you have all your records in memory, treat the resulting active record relation as an array, not SQL.  Use array methods like `select` instead of `where`.  Perhaps:

`@checklists[0].checklist_items.select {|ci| ci.active == true}`

Comment: maybe `active == true` ? anyway it's excess